# What are the cosine functions in JPEG's DCT-II table?

Tags: dct, image-compression, jpeg, cosine

As I understand it from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2aEzeMDHMA), in a JPEG image an 8x8-pixel block is made up of weighted cosine waves, calculated using DCT-II. There are lots of visualizations of these waves, such as this one from the [Wikipedia article on JPEG compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Discrete_cosine_transform):

[image: Visualization of DCTII cosine waves]

I'd like to visualize each of the waves for a given 8x8-pixel block in an image, weighted with values calculated by DCT-II.

Where can I find (or how can I calculate) the 64 cosine functions used in JPEG compression?

Comment: Any more needed?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Either the OP should accept your answer, or point out what more is required for a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those 2D cosine functions are independent of your input image. They are just "cosine waves", or the 64 basis functions that yield 64 coefficients when transforming "$8\times 8$" blocks. Given a $D$ $8\times 8$ matrix for the DCT-II, and a $8\times 8$ image patch $I$, you'll get $64$ coefficients $C$ by:

$$C=DID^T$$

[EDIT] If you want to display the 2D DCT-II functions only, you have to create 2D arrays $D_{h,v}(m,n)$ ($0\le m< M$ and $0\le n< N$) for each couple of horizontal/vertical integer indices $(h,v)$, with $0\le h< H$ and $0\le v< V$, with $H=M$ and $V=N$. Classically for JPEG, $M=N=8$. A formula is (up to a transposition, and possibly a scale factor):

$$D_{h,v}(m,n) = 2\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\eta_h  \eta_v \cos\left(\frac{\pi h}{2M}(2m+1)\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi v}{2N}(2n+1)\right)$$

with $\eta_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ if $x=0$, $\eta_x = 1$ if $x\neq0$. There are a lot of clever implementations, I'll provide the most straightforward. The goal is to get a picture like the following:

[image: 8x8 DCT-II bases]

A pseudo-code version (from Matlab) could be (with the issue of 0-based or 1-based indices):

```
nRow = 8;nCol = 8;
nFreqHoriz = 8;
nFreqVerti = 8;
for iFreqH = 1:nFreqHoriz
    for iFreqV = 1:nFreqVerti
        iFreqHoriz = iFreqH-1;
        iFreqVerti = iFreqV-1;
        normFreqDC = 1/sqrt(2);
        matFreq2D = zeros(nRow,nCol);
        for iRow = 1:nRow
            for iCol = 1:nCol
                iRow0 = iRow-1;
                iCol0 = iCol-1;
                matFreq2D(iRow,iCol) = 2/(sqrt(nFreqHoriz)*sqrt(nFreqVerti))*cos(pi*iFreqHoriz*(2*iRow0+1)/(2*nRow))*cos(pi*iFreqVerti*(2*iCol0+1)/(2*nCol));
                if ~iFreqHoriz ,  matFreq2D(iRow,iCol) =  matFreq2D(iRow,iCol)*normFreqDC;end
                if ~iFreqVerti ,  matFreq2D(iRow,iCol) =  matFreq2D(iRow,iCol)*normFreqDC;end
            end
        end
        sum(matFreq2D(:).^2)
        subplot(nFreqHoriz,nFreqVerti,8*(iFreqV-1)+iFreqH)
        imagesc(matFreq2D);axis off;axis square;colormap gray
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite following, though – I can generate the coefficients with DCT but I'd like to generate the functions for each of the cosine functions in the diagram above. Does the formula you list here do that or compute the DCT?

Comment: In 1D the coefficients are generated as here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#DCT-II. You get 8 basis vectors. In 2D you can get them by multiplying each 1D vector by its transpose (tensor product)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I just don't understand what you're saying. How do I generate the 8 basis vectors? (I assume they are the cosine functions, right?) Do I plug the number of the vector (`n`) into the equation listed on Wikipedia? What does `k` mean in that equation?

Comment: Maybe the SE format is not the most evident ; `k` is an index for each frequency component (see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/58599/15892). You can more or less iuse the formula after  "The general equation for a 2D (N by M image) DCT is defined by the following equation:" in https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Multimedia/node231.html

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I'm a little out of my depth here. In everything I look at, the author seems to assume we already know how to generate those functions. For example, in that second link: "This involves simply computing values for a convolution mask", but it doesn't explain how to do that! Isn't there a simple way to list or state them (which is really what I'm after)? If that's what the function in your answer is, can you give an example of how to calculate one of the functions?

Comment: PS maybe I didn't explain my question well: I just want the functions used to create the visualization above, not calculating the weights for a particular 8x8-pixel block.

Comment: So, OK, let's do it

Comment: Thanks for the update! I don't use Matlab so it will take me a bit to parse it, but much appreciated!

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to share the code used to run the picture, and in some case, it can help to understand how to implement the formula in another language

Comment: Code is much easier to understand for me than a formula :)

Comment: You might want to use tabulated arrays instead